# Asp .Net Core Directoy not found problem when trying to start

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was getting directoryIOException when i tried to run dotnet myProject.dll

I changed this

```
  var webRoot = _environment.WebRootPath;

        services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(
            new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(webRoot, "files")));
```

but now it gives me exception

> [21:47:32 INF] Starting web host [21:47:32 FTL] Host terminated
>   unexpectedly System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: path1    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1,
>   String path2)    at
>   NoPaper.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in
>   C:\Users\JoaoF\source\repos\NoPaper\NoPaper\Startup.cs:line 81
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()

I debugged this and i get the correct path to my `wwwroot` directory, so why does it say it is null?

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config, there is a path to your dotnet.exe, you might have to specify the full path  make sure your PATH includes the dotnet.exe location